# How to show/hide a model in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my project page load model popup will appear if any of projects can be available for login user it can be show other wise not show in that model I have two anchor tags

1. My Projects
2. Add New Projects
3. My Projects Menu Click one form1 will be display?
4. Add New Projects Menu Click second form2 will be display?

Here my model code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center m-b-30">
    <a href="index.html" class="text-success">
      <span>All Projects</span>
    </a>
  </h2>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" id="mp"> <i class="mdi mdi-account md-18"></i> My Projects</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" id="anp"> <i class="mdi mdi-plus md-18"></i> Add New Project </a>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="myprojects">
    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="username">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="username" required="" placeholder="Michael Zenaty">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="emailaddress" required="" placeholder="john@deo.com">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom">
          <input id="checkbox11" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label for="checkbox11">
                                                                I accept <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group account-btn text-center m-t-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Sign Up Free</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

  <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="addnewprojects">
    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="username">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="username" required="" placeholder="Michael Zenaty">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="emailaddress" required="" placeholder="john@deo.com">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom">
          <input id="checkbox11" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label for="checkbox11">
                                                                I accept <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group account-btn text-center m-t-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Sign Up Free</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myprojects").hide();
    $("#mp").click(function(e) {
        $("#myprojects").show();
        $("#mp").hide();

    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addnewprojects").hide();
    $("#anp").click(function(e) {
        $("#addnewprojects").show();
        $("#anp").hide();

    });
});  

</script>
```

my intention is which menu I will click that form will display in the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now need to add add `$(document).ready` twice and adding couple of hide and show for working snippet. Run snippet for working example.

```js
$("#myprojects").hide();
$("#mp").click(function(e) {
  $("#myprojects").show();
  $("#addnewprojects").hide();
 // $(this).hide();
  $("#anp").show();

});
$("#anp").click(function(e) {
  $("#addnewprojects").show();
  $("#myprojects").hide();
  //$(this).hide();
  $("#mp").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center m-b-30">
    <a href="index.html" class="text-success">
      <span>All Projects</span>
    </a>
  </h2>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" id="mp"> <i class="mdi mdi-account md-18"></i> My Projects</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#" id="anp"> <i class="mdi mdi-plus md-18"></i> Add New Project </a>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="myprojects">
    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="username">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="username" required="" placeholder="Michael Zenaty">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="emailaddress" required="" placeholder="john@deo.com">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom">
          <input id="checkbox11" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label for="checkbox11">
                                                                I accept <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group account-btn text-center m-t-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Sign Up Free1</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

  <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="addnewprojects">
    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="username">Name1</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="username" required="" placeholder="Michael Zenaty">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="emailaddress">Email address1</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="emailaddress" required="" placeholder="john@deo.com">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-25">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-b-20">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom">
          <input id="checkbox11" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label for="checkbox11">
                                                                I accept <a href="#">Terms and Conditions1</a>
                                                            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group account-btn text-center m-t-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Sign Up Free [Add New Project]</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: on page load my projects display but on my localhost it will run Add New Project @shree

Comment: on load first i will see the My Projects Page then i will click add new projects then new projects page display and also two menus can see on top also

Comment: Just remove $(this).hide(); to show two menu and  Its see My Projects  when load.